Does sign of random noise really matter?
I was studying about Diffusion models in deep learning and came across the substitution $$x_t = \sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}x_0 + \sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon\implies x_0=\dfrac{x_t-\sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon}{\sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}},$$
where $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. So can we write $$x_0=\dfrac{x_t+\sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon}{\sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}}$$ instead, since picking a positive number is equally as likely as picking a negative number under a standard univariate Gaussian?

$x_0=\dfrac{x_t+\sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon}{\sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}}$ corresponds to $x_t = \sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}x_0 - \sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon$.  So, yes you can do this since the distribution of $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ is symmetric about $0$, but it is unconventional and may risk confusion unless you ensure consistency over correct signs.    Rather like using $\frac{\mu_X-X}{\sigma_X}$ instead of the usual $\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$ by arguing both have expectations of $0$ and variances of $1$.

@Henry would you consider writing that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted since that is exactly what I was looking for?

When defining a stochastic proces, it does not matter if a white noise term is added or subtracted, since the distribution is symmetrical.
However you need to be consistent in how you apply it, or otherwise potential errors can be introduced.
For example if you have computed $$x_t = \sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}x_0 + \sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon$$
Then later on you can’t compute $$x_0=\dfrac{x_t+\sqrt{1-\overline\alpha_t}\epsilon}{\sqrt{\overline\alpha_t}},$$ using the same $\epsilon$ and $x_t$ that you got from the first formula, as that would clearly get you to the wrong value of $x_0$.

Could you explain why the sign of epsilon might have an impact on the program (say, np.random.normal(0, 1) in python)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
